# Paginación en Aspx Bootstrap

Tags: asp, bootstrap-3

Estoy intentado paginar varios items, he intentado de diversas formas pero por alguna razón no he logrado hacerlo. Lo que necesito es ir mostrando de 5 en cinco los resultados.

Si alguien puede ayudarme muy agradecido.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
         <div class="panel-body">
            <center>
               <h5>
                  <div class="row">
                     <br />
                     Num - Lugar - Fecha
                  </div>
               </h5>
            </center>
         </div>
         <ul class="list-group" id="Items">
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46047   - Patio de Caña</br>21/12/2017 9:41:02 a. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46051   - Patio de Caña</br>21/12/2017 2:33:53 p. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46070   - Patio de Caña</br>21/12/2017 1:37:05 p. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46069   - Taller</br>21/12/2017 2:38:08 p. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46048   - Gasolinera</br>21/12/2017 2:37:09 p. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46072   - Gasolinera</br>21/12/2017 2:38:08 p. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46073   - Servicio Rapido</br>21/12/2017 2:37:43 p. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46075   - Servicio Rapido</br>21/12/2017 2:28:15 p. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46050   - Transporte</br>21/12/2017 12:00:00 a. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46049   - Transporte</br>21/12/2017 12:00:00 a. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46068   - Transporte</br>21/12/2017 12:00:00 a. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46074   - Transporte</br>21/12/2017 12:00:00 a. m.</li>
            <li style="font-size: 0.875em;"class="list-group-item">46076   - Transporte</br>21/12/2017 12:00:00 a. m.</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podria ser una opcion, tienes que usar javascript o jquery para que sea dinamico

```js
//declaras el contenido que tendra cada lista
var items = '[{"Id":1,"Title":"46047 - Patio de Caña<br>21/12/2017 9:41:02 a. m."},{"Id":2,"Title":"46051 - Patio de Caña<br>21/12/2017 2:33:53 p. m."},{"Id":3,"Title":"46070 - Patio de Caña<br>21/12/2017 1:37:05 p. m."},{"Id":4,"Title":"46069 - Taller<br>21/12/2017 2:38:08 p. m."},{"Id":5,"Title":"46048 - Gasolinera<br>21/12/2017 2:37:09 p. m."},{"Id":6,"Title":"46072 - Gasolinera<br>21/12/2017 2:38:08 p. m."},{"Id":7,"Title":"46073 - Servicio Rapido<br>21/12/2017 2:37:43 p. m."},{"Id":8,"Title":"46075 - Servicio Rapido<br>21/12/2017 2:28:15 p. m."},{"Id":9,"Title":"46050 - Transporte<br>21/12/2017 12:00:00 a. m."},{"Id":10,"Title":"46068 - Transporte<br>21/12/2017 12:00:00 a. m."},{"Id":11,"Title":"46074 - Transporte<br>21/12/2017 12:00:00 a. m."},{"Id":12,"Title":"46076 - Transporte<br>21/12/2017 12:00:00 a. m."}]';
var pager = {};
pager.items = JSON.parse(items);
//declaras cuantas li se mostraran por pagina
pager.itemsPerPage = 3;
pagerInit(pager);

//para insertar el contenido de las listes vacias al html
function bindList() {
  var pgItems = pager.pagedItems[pager.currentPage];
  $("#Items").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < pgItems.length; i++) {
    var option = $('<li class="list-group-item">');
    for (var key in pgItems[i]) {
      option.html(pgItems[i][key]);
    }
    $("#Items").append(option);
  }
}
//boton previo
function prevPage() {
  pager.prevPage();
  bindList();
}
//boton proximos

function nextPage() {
  pager.nextPage();
  bindList();
}

function pagerInit(p) {
  p.pagedItems = [];
  p.currentPage = 0;
  if (p.itemsPerPage === undefined) {
    p.itemsPerPage = 5;
  }
  p.prevPage = function() {
    if (p.currentPage > 0) {
      p.currentPage--;
    }
  };
  p.nextPage = function() {
    if (p.currentPage < p.pagedItems.length - 1) {
      p.currentPage++;
    }
  };
  init = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < p.items.length; i++) {
      if (i % p.itemsPerPage === 0) {
        p.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / p.itemsPerPage)] = [p.items[i]];
      } else {
        p.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / p.itemsPerPage)].push(p.items[i]);
      }
    }
  };
  init();
}
$(function() {
  bindList();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <center>
          <h5>
            <div class="row">
              <br /> Num - Lugar - Fecha
            </div>
          </h5>
        </center>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group" id="Items">
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
        <li style="font-size: 0.875em;" class="list-group-item"></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="myList" class="list-group"></ul>
          <ul class="pager">
            <li class="previous"><a href="" onclick="prevPage(); return false;">«</a></li>
            <li class="next"><a href="" onclick="nextPage(); return false;">»</a></li>
          </ul>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @LuisFernando genial tu respuesta.